# Optimizing search request in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, search

I am creating a search feature that takes a keyword and look in every specified columns in 3 tables for my database.

Table 1 is Utilisateurs

Table 2 is ReserveLocaux

Table 3 is called Utilisateurs_ReserveLocaux and it is the table that links Users and Reservations with their primary key.

Here is what I came up with so far

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Search_ReservLocaux
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @keyword as varchar(100),
 @noUsager as int
AS

declare @searchTerm as varchar(105) = cast('%' + @keyword  + '%' as     varchar(105))

--Select all reservations information where allowed field include search term
--where the user making the request participates in
--where additional user are part of the same reservation
select distinct  a.NoReservation,a.ApprobationProf,a.Commentaire,a.Date,a.HeureDébut,a.HeureFin,a     .NoLocal,a.NoReservation,a.PersonnesExt from ReserveLocaux a 
join Utilisateurs_ReserveLocaux b on a.NoReservation = b.NoReservation
join Utilisateurs c on c.id= b.NoUsager 
where(
     a.[Date] like @searchTerm or
     a.[HeureDébut] like @searchTerm or
     a.[HeureFin] like @searchTerm or
     a.[Commentaire] like @searchTerm or
     a.[CommentaireGardien] like @searchTerm or
     a.[ApprobationProf] like @searchTerm or
     a.[NoLocal] like @searchTerm or
     a.[Actif] like @searchTerm or
     a.[PersonnesExt] like @searchTerm or
     b.[NoUsager] like @searchTerm or
     b.[NoReservation] like @searchTerm or
     c.[NomUsager]  like @searchTerm or
     c.[PrenomUsager] like @searchTerm 
  )
  and(a.Actif is null or a.Actif = 1)

  and b.NoUsager = @noUsager 
Return
GO

exec Search_ReservLocaux 'saoindoaisn',3
go
```

Basically, with this search I get most of the informations I need. The problem is that I also require to look up every users that have the same reservation number found in the Utilisateurs_ReserveLocaux table which goes as is :

```
|Id_User|Id_Reservation|
   3         45
   4         45
   5         32
```

I need to access user #3(the one who is doing the search) and user #4 which is called  "saoindoaisn".

I know the problem is in the last line of the where statement

```
b.NoUsager = @noUsager
```

but if I remove it, I lose security on my data because the user doing the search could access everything that he isn't participating in and if I keep it, I can't access the required data.

Can someone help me find an alternative to this line?

PS: Sorry if it is not 100% clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
b.Id_Reservation in (select id_reservation 
                     from Utilisateurs_ReserveLocaux url2
                     where url2.NoUsager = @noUsager 
                    )
```

It is a bit hard to tell if your overall query logic could be simplified, but I think this does what you want for the outer `where` clause.

Comment: It does not work. Error :**  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**   The query returns every reservation made by @noUsager.

Comment: @ThallForms . . . Your sample data has only one row in that table per user.  The more general method is to use `in` rather than `=`.

Comment: I modifier your query so instead of b.Id_reservation = (code) , I used b.Id_reservation IN (code) and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Actually In command is dangerous if sub query returns null values.

Comment: @RGS . . . If the subquery returns `NULL` values, then there are no matches in the table and the expression returns false (or at least not-true).  I see nothing dangerous about that.  Perhaps you are confusing `in` with `not in`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Sorry, I misunderstood. Thank you for your clarification.